# Thymeleaf Templating th:data=http://www.somesite.com || org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as assignation sequence

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, thymeleaf, templating

Here is the template.

After I run the process function from the TemplateEngine, I receive this error `org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as assignation sequence: "data=http://www.somesite.com" (template: "someFile.html" - line 5, col 2)`

I've tried doing it a handful of different ways and keep getting the same result.

```
<div class="someClass" th:id="${divId}">
    <object class="someClass" type="application/pdf" 
    th:data="'|${url}|'">
        <p>You don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.
                    <a th:href="@{|${url}|}">
                        Click here to download PDF file.
                    </a>
                </p>
        </object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're tyring to pass a `string` to th: when it expect a `expression`.

Change this:

```
th:data="'|${url}|'"
```

To this:

```
th:data=${url}
```

Remember to change the other elements that are also as string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need most of the `|` characters (as using literal substitutions don't make a difference here.  The code you posted should look like this:

```
<div class="someClass" th:id="${divId}">
    <object class="someClass" type="application/pdf" th:data="${url}">
        <p>
            You don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.
            <a th:href="${url}">Click here to download PDF file.</a>
        </p>
    </object>
</div>
```

That being said, the error you indicated usually comes with using `th:with` incorrectly, and since I don't see that anywhere in the code you've given us, I doubt you have located the root cause of the problem.